# Why doesnt command execute successfully if i use variables?

Tags: linux, unix

I have the following script

```
WSO2_SCRIPT="JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh"
WSO2_LOG="/var/log/autopilot/wso2is/autopilot-wso2is-initd.log"


${WSO2_SCRIPT} start >> ${WSO2_LOG} 2>&1 || echo failed

JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start >> /var/log/autopilot/wso2is/autopilot-wso2is-initd.log 2>&1 || echo failedagain
```

The third line of the code results in failure as I have "failed" echoed?

However the fourth line is successful and I don't get "failedagain" echoed.

Line 3 and 4 should result in exactly the same thing. Only difference is I am using variables in in line 3, and being explicit in line 4.

Why does using variables result in a failure?

Comment: Hint: check the redirected output.....

Comment: I have, the stdout and stderr is being sent to ${WSO2_LOG} in both? they are both identical in terms of redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When variables are expanded without quotes, they undergo word splitting and pathname expansion, but **not** shell grammar parsing.

This means that you can put the following in variables:

- Multiple arguments (including command name) to be split up on spaces and spaces only
- Globs like `*.txt` to be expanded

It also means that you can not put anything of the following in variables:

- Redirections
- Quotes
- Pipes
- Backgrounding `&`
- Conditionals and loops, including `if` and `[[ .. ]]`
- Brace and parenthesis groups
- Parameter expansion
- Command substitutions
- Process substitutions
- and as you've discovered: variable assignments

If you want to pass any of the above around as a variable, you should use a function and refer to the function instead. If you don't care about security and good practice, you can also use `eval` to evaluate a text string as shell code.